# C# Distance tracking Loop in Unity wont work; Working with Neural Network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been working on this school project about Neural Networks for a while and i got about everything to work except for the fitness, here i Thought i made a simple loop that will record the Distance for the Float ReaverOld, wait one Second (with the Invoke), then record the distance for the float ReaverNew. It should record the fitness with the fitness float; fitdistance = (ReaverNew - ReaverOld); (the FitDistance is correctly connected to the Neural Network, i did check that)

My program runs fine, but when i use the Debug log command to check the variables for Fitdistance and Transform.LocalPosition.y or x, i just get back Zero. I went based off this tutorial https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html and was told that a loop using a Invoke is possible. I don't understand why its not tracking the position at all, Ive also tried both Vector2 and 3.

```
public void Point() // use for calling on a Distance Function function
//already in a loop, dont double loop for whatever reason
{
    if(ReaverPos = true) {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            Debug.Log (transform.localPosition.y);
            float ReaverOld = transform.localPosition.y + transform.localPosition.x;
                Invoke("Shine", 1f);

    }

}

public void Shine() //Second call on from Point, Endless loop for Checking Distance based on the Invoke since it last 1 second
{
        float ReaverNew = transform.localPosition.y + transform.localPosition.x;
            fitDistance = (ReaverNew - ReaverOld);
            //Debug.Log (fitDistance);

}
```

Comment: `float ReaverOld` is a local variable inside `Point()` - you cannot access it inside `Shine()`

Comment: I already had everything present before though, Both ReaverOld and ReaverNew are variables both made outside both the Point() and Shine()

Comment: You need to provide a better code example then (see [mcve]), as this one does not compile and as such doesn't help us figure out the problem